# What SQLite column data type is required to handle this?

Tags: sqlite, python-3.7

```
 def material_code(self):

    tableType = self.comboBox.currentText()
    tableGrade = self.comboBox_2.currentText()
    tableType = tableType.lower()

    c.execute('SELECT prefix FROM ' + tableType + ' WHERE grade = ' + tableGrade)

    prefix_code = c.fetchone()
    print(prefix_code[0])

    conn.commit()
```

I am getting a common error it seems...

sqlite3 unrecognized token:

This error occurs when the return is a combination of numeric/char and other special chars are present in the field.

Sometimes it works if the field only contains numerics or chars but not a combination.

The drop down (tableGrade) that i am SELECTING with should find an exact match every single time as the drop down is populated from the same table/column.

Also what can i do to my query to protect from injection attacks please?

[image: column data]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the column contains numerics and/or chars then you must consider that its data type is `TEXT`, although **SQLite** is not strict when it comes to data types since you can define a column's data type as `INT` and store in it any kind of text.
What you must change is the way you select the data.
You must use placeholders `?` (parameter markers) like this:

```
c.execute("SELECT prefix FROM " + tableType + " WHERE grade = ?", (tableGrade,))
```

where `tableType` is the variable holding the name of your table and `tableGrade` is a string value holding the grade on which you want to filter.